# How can I dynamically delete events from this PrimeNG FullCalendar (clicking on an event)?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG Full Calendar component, this one: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar

That is based on the Angular FullCalendar component, this one: https://fullcalendar.io/

Here you can find my entire code: https://bitbucket.org/dgs_poste_team/soc_calendar/src/master/

So I have a calendar like this:

[image]

What I am trying to implement at this stage is that when the user click on a specific event, all the events into this calendar will be deleted (in a second stage I will implement that only the specific clicked event will be deleted, but at the moment I am keeping the logic as simple as possible).

So this is the class controlling my calendar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendar } from 'primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fullcalendar',
  templateUrl: './fullcalendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fullcalendar.component.css']
})
export class FullcalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];
  options: any;
  header: any;

  //people: any[];

  @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendar;

  calendar:any;


  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.eventService.getEvents().then(events => { this.events = events;});

    this.eventService.getEvents().subscribe(events => { this.events = events.map((event) => {
      var date = new Date(event.start);
      var hour = date.getHours();
      //event['backgroundColor'] = hour === 7? 'red': (hour === 7 ? 'green' : 'black');

      //let events = this.calendar.getEvents();
      //events[

      console.log("EVENTS: " + this.events);

      if(hour === 7) {
        event['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
      }
      else if(hour === 15) {
        event['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
      }
      else if(hour === 23) {
        event['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
      }


      return event;
    })});

    this.options = {
        plugins:[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin ],
        defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        nextDayThreshold: '09:00:00',
        allDayDefault: false,

        dateClick: (dateClickEvent) =>  {         // <-- add the callback here as one of the properties of `options`
          console.log("DATE CLICKED !!!");
        },

        eventClick: (eventClickEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT CLICKED !!!");
          console.log(eventClickEvent.event.id);
          //this.eventService.removeEventById(eventClickEvent.event.id);
          this.eventService.removeEventById(eventClickEvent.event.id).subscribe(events => console.log(events));


            /*
            events => { this.events = events.map((event) => {
            var date = new Date(event.start);
            var hour = date.getHours();

            console.log("EVENTS: " + this.events);

            if(hour === 7) {
              event['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
            }
            else if(hour === 15) {
              event['backgroundColor'] = 'green';
            }
            else if(hour === 23) {
              event['backgroundColor'] = 'black';
            }

            return event;
          })});
          */
        },

        eventDragStop: (eventDragStopEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT DRAG STOP !!!");
        },

        eventReceive: (eventReceiveEvent) => {
          console.log(eventReceiveEvent);
          //eventReceiveEvent.event.setAllDay(false, {maintainDuration: true});



          //eventReceiveEvent['backgroundColor'] = 'red';
          this.eventService.addEvent(eventReceiveEvent);
        }
    };

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.calendar = this.fullcalendar.getCalendar();
    console.log("CALENDAR: " + this.calendar);

  }

}
```

As you can see into the **ngOnInit()** method I am subscribing the **getEvents()** method of a service that return the list of rendered events as Observable (I am doing in this way because in the returned output I am handling different color for different events type, but this is not strictly related to my question...it works fine).

So, as you can see this component class contains this hook method **eventClick: (eventClickEvent)** handling the click on an event of my calendar. I was thinking to call a delete events method defined into my service and render it again but it is not working (I have done several try and it is not working). I am also not sure that this is the correct approach to the problem.

From what I can understand into the **ngOnInit()** method I have the subscription to my calendar event array, so chainging the content of this array this change is published and it should rendered again, I tried also this but it is not working...so I think that probably I am missing something in the Angular logic.

This is the code of my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {

  private events = [];

  /*
  private events = [
    {id: 1, title: 'All Day Event', start: '2017-02-01'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Long Event', start: '2017-02-07', end: '2017-02-10'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Repeating Event', start: '2017-02-09T16:00:00'},
    {id: 3, title: 'test', start: '2017-02-20T07:00:00'},
  ];
  */

  private people = [
    {id: 1, name: "PERSONA 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "PERSONA 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "PERSONA 3"},
    {id: 4, name: "PERSONA 4"},
    {id: 5, name: "PERSONA 5"},
  ]

  public eventData = new BehaviorSubject(this.events);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEvents(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.eventData.asObservable();
  }


  addEvent(event) {
    //console.log(event.event.start);
    //console.log(event);
    const newEvent = {id: 5, title: event.event.title, start: event.event.start, end: event.event.end};
    this.events.push(newEvent);
    this.eventData.next([...this.events]);
    //console.log(this.events);
  }

  removeEventById(id:number): Observable<any[]>  {
    console.log("EVENTDATA: " + this.eventData.getValue());

    return this.eventData.asObservable();
  }


  /*
  removeEventById = (id:number) => {
    this.events = [];
    //return this.events.filter(each=>each.id!=id);

  }
  */

  getPeople(): Promise<any[]> {
    return Promise.all(this.people)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          return res;
        })
  }

}
```

So what is wrong? What am I missing? What could be a smart solution to correctly handle my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there you few things that should be in place.

1. For Removing all events.

   **In events.service**

> ```
> public deleteEvents() {
>    this.events = [];
>    this.eventData.next(this.events);
>  }
> ```

In **fullCalendar.component.ts** fullCalendar options :-

> ```
> eventClick: (eventClickEvent) => {
>       console.log("EVENT CLICKED !!!");
>       this.eventService.deleteEvents();
>     }
> ```

2. For Removing specific events.

First in your calendar a unique id should be present for each event. Currently in your addEvent method you are giving same Id to every event. i.e. 5. First lets fix that.

```
public currentId = 1;

public addEvent() {
      const newEvent = {id: this.currentId++, title: event.event.title, start: event.event.start, end: event.event.end};
   //Remaining Add Event Code.
}
```

This way you will have a unique id to event, whenever it will be added to your calendar.

Now on event clicked you are calling a method, i.e. removeEventById(). That should be written as :-

```
removeEventById(id): Observable<any[]>  {
    this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event.id!==+id);
    this.eventData.next(this.events);
    return this.eventData.asObservable();
}
```

Note :- the id you receive from event click object is in string and the id you have in array is number. Hence i have added + above in id received to parse it in number to match id and remove necessary item. without it the removal will not work.

In **fullCalendar.component.ts** fullCalendar options :-

```
eventClick: (eventClickEvent) => {
      console.log("EVENT CLICKED !!!");        
 this.eventService.removeEventById(eventClickEvent.event.id).subscribe(events => console.log(events));
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

primeng fullcalendar developed from fullcalendar.io, you can filter data then assign to eventData. I created your code in [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/an-primeng-ndnuui)

```
 this.eventService.removeEventById(eventClickEvent.event.id).subscribe(events => console.log(events));
```

in your method

```
removeEventById(id:number): Observable<any[]>  {
    this.events=this.events.filter(each=>each.id!=id);
    this.eventData.next([...this.events]);
    return this.eventData.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `Observables`, you can use the `map` operator combined with `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

removeEventById(id:number): Observable<any[]>  {    
    return this.getEvents()
        .pipe(
            map(items => items.filter(item => item.id == id))
        );    
}
```

[The whole work example can be seen at the stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo-kqrehm?file=src/app/myServices.ts)

So your service could look like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyServices {
    private events = [
        {   
          id: 1,
          title: 'Foo 1',
          date: '2020-06-07'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Foo 2',
          date: '2020-06-08'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Foo 3',
          date: '2020-06-05'
        }
    ];

    public eventData = new BehaviorSubject(this.events);

    constructor() { }

    sayHello() {        
        console.log("Say Hello");
    }

    getEvents(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.eventData.asObservable();
    }


  addEvent(event) {
    const newEvent = {id: 5, title: event.event.title, 
        start: event.event.start, end: event.event.end};
    this.events.push(newEvent);
    this.eventData.next(Object.assign({}, this.events));
  }

  removeEventById(id:number): Observable<any[]>  {    
    return this.getEvents()
      .pipe(
        map(items => items.filter(item => item.id == id))
      );    
  }    
}
```

and `your.component.ts` could look like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    options: any;
    eventsModel: any;
    @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendarComponent;
    @ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;

    constructor(private myServices: MyServices){
        this.myServices.sayHello();
    }

    eventClick(model) {
        this.myServices.removeEventById(model.id)
            .subscribe(s => this.eventsModel = s);       
    }
```